# Show the item width an certain ID that is received by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have several content items on the page all of the are hidden and they have each a unique ID. #data serves as a temporary stack.

```html
    <div id="data"></div>
    <div id="item1212">...</div>
    <div id="item2323">...</div>
    <div id="item3434">...</div>
    <div id="item4545">...</div>
```

an Ajaxrequest gives me back a certain ID

```js
$('#data').load('http://someURL');
```

fills the #data:

```html
<div id="data">2323</div>
```

width this lines I make my correspondig item visible:

```js
var theID = $('#data').text().val();  
$('#item'+theID).toggleClass('visible');
```

This was my idea. Guess: Ist does not work cause it fails to read #data and use the value as a string. Its alwas an object (?).

I save the value first in html cause I dont know how to save a ajax-result (its always a string value) to a JS variable.

But I guess you have much better ideas how to solve my Problem: Show item width an certain ID that is receved by ajax

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your logic works fine (aside from the fact you don't need `val()`), you just need to execute it *after* the `load()` call completes as it is asynchronous. Currently you're trying to access the new content before it exists. To do that you can use the callback parameter, like this:

```
$('#data').load('http://someURL', function() {
  var theID = $('#data').text();
  $('#item' + theID).toggleClass('visible');
});
```

Comment: Thank you! asynchronous was the key!